# Django-AWS S3, unable to delete bucket objects

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a Django project with MySQL storage and media objects (images) are being stored in AWS S3 simple storage.

Admin can upload images through admin panel and its being displayed in website too.

When admin delete objects , it gets deleted in MySQL but it's associated images persists in S3 bucket.

SETTINGS.PY

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = ''
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f"{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.me-south-1.amazonaws.com"
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'news.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
```

STORAGE_BACKENDS.PY

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
from django.conf import settings


class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    default_acl = 'public-read'
    file_overwrite = False
```

I am user details as attached,

[image]

Comment: The problem is that filefield persists the files even if the models object gets deleted, to delete the file you must do it yourself like `models_object.file_field_name.delete(save=False)`

Comment: Appreciate it , I will try to implement it

Answer (score 2):

As Luiz said, the files persist after deleting the object. I recommend to create a signal to delete the files after the object has been deleted:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=YourModel)
def remove_image_file_from_s3_on_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.your_field_name.delete(save=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `django-cleanup` app , its fairly easy to setup https://pypi.org/project/django-cleanup/

In older version of Django, when a model instance is deleted it would delete associated media files too but in latest versions its not.

The above app can be installed and add to the app list, later if a model instance edited or deleted it would do the same in AWS S3 storage too

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).